# Ringtone Intent : detect Cancel button or None choice

Tags: android

I open the Ringtone intent to select a sound.

- I can choose "None" in the list.
- I can cancel my choose with the cancel button.

How can I detect if the user selected the Cancel button (to keep previous choice) or "None" ?

Because in onActivityResult, all parameters are the same.

[image: Ringtone choice list]

Intent creation :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, R.string.pref_notification_sound_defaut);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, Uri.parse(myUri));
this.startActivityForResult(intent,5);
```

And onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // with Cancel button or None choice :
    // requestCode == 0
    // resultCode == 5
    // data == null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, cancel button will automatically revert to the previously selected sound.

You should change the value only if `resultCode` is `Activity.RESULT_OK`

Comment: Thanks. But if there was a previous choice, with None I must save that the user wants no sound. And if he cancels, I have to keep the previous one... But I receive no data with the Cancel button and None choice :/

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point entirely, When the user selects None `onActovityResult` will still be called, but the uri in `data` will be null, you don't need to listen to the cancel button.
I believe you store the uri String in a preference?

Comment: yes, I don't need to listen to the cancel button : that's the problem, how to prevent this ? With None AND Cancel, it goes to the onActivityResult method... (requestCode and resultCode and data are the same).
I would like to distinguish "I want no sound"(None) and "let the previous choice" (Cancel button)

Comment: The result code for Cancel is 0. Yet, for none(or any other successful selection) is -1

Comment: At least, you are guaranteed that for Cancel the resultCode will never be -1